# what are the differences between scanf() and fscanf()?

Tags: c

what are the differences between scanf() and fscanf()?

thanks

Comment: When using either (or any other `scanf` variation) remember to check the return value for correctness: `if (scanf(...) != NUMBER_OF_CONVERSIONS) /* oops */;`

Answer (score 11):

`scanf()` is exactly identical to `fscanf()` with `stdin` as the first argument.

Answer (score 9):

For `scanf()` you always read from standard input and for `fscanf()` you specify the file input stream.

Compare:

```
int  scanf ( const char * format, ... );
int fscanf ( FILE * stream, const char * format, ... );
```

Answer (score 2):

Just google it (emphasis mine):

> http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/scanf/
>
> ```
> int  scanf ( const char * format, ... );
> ```
>
> Read formatted data from ***stdin***

And

> http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fscanf/
>
> ```
> int fscanf ( FILE * stream, const char * format, ... );
> ```
>
> Read formatted data from ***stream***

Comment: cplusplus.com is not a very reliable reference. If I remember correctly, its documentation of `scanf` even has some mistakes regarding the return value.

Comment: @R: Thanks, that's good to know. Could you point me to more reliable reference sources?

Answer (score 0):

From the third paragraph of `fscanf(3)` manpage:

```
   The scanf() function reads input from the standard input stream
   stdin, fscanf() reads input from the stream pointer stream, and
   sscanf() reads its input from the character string pointed to by
   str.
```

You might have been able to guess that from the `SYNOPSIS`:

```
   int scanf(const char *format, ...);
   int fscanf(FILE *stream, const char *format, ...);
```

:)

Answer (score -3):

scanf() : data transfer from I/O to memory(variables)
fscanf() : data transfer form memory(variables) to file.

Comment: Please be more descriptive in your answer. As it stands it isn't very high-quality.